# Ballerina Maven Build Fails - toml parser

Tags: java, maven, ballerina

I checked out [Ballerina](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/) and built using `mvn clean install`. I get the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven->plugin:3.1.1:spotbugs (spotbugs) on project toml-parser: Execution spotbugs >of goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.1:spotbugs failed: Java >returned: 1 -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute >?goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.1:spotbugs (spotbugs) on project toml-parser: Execution spotbugs of goal com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:3.1.1:spotbugs failed: Java returned: 1

Build Environment:

- macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6)
- Java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
- Apache Maven 3.6.0

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does it build if you check out one of the other release tags?

Comment: What is the actual error if you run the build with debug `-X`, there should be more information why `spotbugs-maven-plugin` failed.

Comment: @Kerry: No. It fails with the same error.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki: This is what I get when run with `-X`. https://pastebin.com/9ZazMawu

Comment: You're going to have to give some details of your build environment e.g. OS, java version, maven version etc

Comment: Can you provide the information Kerry has mentioned above? (OS, JDK version, Maven version)

Comment: I edited the question and described the build environment. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out it successfully builds with Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Ballerina does not support Java 11 yet, which is the reason for the stated issue. Thanks @Kerry, @Karol Dowbecki, @Manuri.